# Least number characters which can make a set of strings unique

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, prefix

What is the least number characters (starting from 1st character) which can make a set of strings unique.

For example,
set of strings:

```
{
    'january',
    'february',
    'march',
    'april',
    'may',
    'june',
    'july'
}
```

Now, we cannot use just 1st  character since 'j' is both in 'june' as well as 'july' (also, 'm' is in 'march' and 'may').
We also cannot use 1st 2 characters as 'ma' is both in 'march' and 'may'.

But, we can use 1st 3 characters!

What can be an optimal algorithm to return this number (besides an obvious brute force) ?

Comment: So you're looking for the minimal set of indices such that no two elements have the same character at each index?

Comment: Oh, nope, I misunderstood. You want the smallest set of **consecutive** characters, right?

Comment: @KyleStrand: smallest initial segment, I think.

Comment: @Steve: exactly! This is a real-life problem one of which is depicted in the problem description where we daily use first 3 letters to denote a month since they uniquely identify the month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you can optimize is to do a binary search over the size of prefix needed. The function is monotonous- if a given number of chars n is enough, then any value larger than n will also do.

Second - you may compute rolling hashes for each string so that you can get the hash code for a given prefix of each string in constant time. Thus you will have to verify numbers(hash codes) for uniqueness instead of a string which of course is faster. I suggest a rolling hash like in [rabin-karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm).

Comment: I was actually looking for an answer similar to given by you where you mentioned to calculate the rolling hashes. I wanted to know whether coding rolling hashes solution in 30 minutes is feasible or not?

Comment: @Sankalp: depends hugely on the programmer. Different programmers can easily differ by a factor of 10 to write code for the same algorithm, according to their skill, experience and familiarity with the algorithm they're coding. Language also makes some difference, and available libraries might make a large difference depending on the task. That said, 30 minutes is optimistic for almost any programming task unless you know *exactly* what you're doing before you start.

Comment: @SteveJessop actaully 10 times is quite modest. I would say a factor of 50 or 100 is more realistic. I am a long term competitor and for a classic algorithmic problem take about 10-15 times less time than a "regular" programmer. Still there are people able to write most algorithms several times faster than me. I personally take about 5 minutes to implement the algorithm described above, but I believe an estimate of 30 mins to 1 hour is somewhat realistic for someone who has never written such thing before.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: fair enough. I was thinking of practical programming tasks, and I picked 10 as a plausible difference rather than any kind of limit. I realise that competition performance is a different beast, about which I know nothing :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the data and compare the index of the first character that differs between adjacent entries. This has complexity of O(N log N) or the complexity of sorting.

If you can incorporate the index calculation *into* the compare function, you can get the result as a side effect: the result should be the maximum index encountered by the compare function.

As Steve Jessop commented, it may be that there's no solution to the problem. One could indeed first calculate the minimum length of the entries. Another option, if one can freely implement a comparison function, is to return -1 if the comparison function has ever encountered an end of string.

```
int global_max = 0;
int compare(const char *a, const char *b) {
    int c=0;
    int result;  // result of comparison -- set as zero if an error has occured
    if (global_max < 0) return 0;
    do {
       if (*a==0 || *b==0) { global_max = -1; return 0; }
       c++;
    } while ((result = (*a++ - *b++)) == 0);
    if (c>global_max) global_max = c;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 A good approach. Still please keep in mind you should take into account the length of the strings for the sorting.

Comment: One thing you could do is to chop each string to the length of the shortest (in this case `"may"`). Any answer found using these shortened strings is correct, and if you cannot find an answer at all using the substrings then one string is an initial substring of another, and so no solution exists. Imagine if there were a month called `May` and another called `Maybruary`. Anyway, creating the substrings likely costs runtime but if you do find that you have to write additional code to take into account the length of the strings, then making them all the same length might save that.

Comment: This approach can be optimized by generating the answer during the time we sort the strings since we are comparing the strings during sorting also!